# MVC 3 : How to get event if form validated correctly and will post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

Basically I am trying to solve the simple problem of if my form validates correctly, I want to basically show an overlay on the screen before doing the post to the server.

I keep thinking this is easy, and I am just missing something.

From the example below (not compilable code) is there a way to do this using the client side validation provided, or do I basically need to handle the client side using straight jquery validation, and then submit?

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

// Html

```
@Html.BeginForm( "Foo", "Bar" )
{
  <div class="grid_2">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PaymentDetails.FirstName)
  </div>
  <div class="grid_3">
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentDetails.FirstName)%>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_2">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PaymentDetails.LastName)
  </div>
  <div class="grid_3">
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentDetails.LastName)%>
  </div>

   <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  value="SUBMIT" style="float: left;" />
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook up a submit handler with jQuery and then check if the form is valid inside it.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }    
});
```

Comment: This is was what was needed. Unfortunately when I tried it originally, we accidentally had UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set to false because of another issue.  Once we set that to true we were good.  thanks